# Using dynamic finders to specify NOT NULL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, dynamic-finders

I very often want to use dynamic finders to specify NOT NULL. So…

this works:

```
Widget.find_all_by_color('blue')
```

this works:

```
Widget.find_all_by_color(nil)
```

But how can I do

```
SELECT * FROM `widgets` WHERE `color` IS NOT NULL;
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Widget.all(:conditions => "color IS NOT NULL")
```

Comment: Yep, I knew all those, thanks guys. I guess there is no way to do it with a dynamic finder. KandadaBoggu gets the answer because his is 5 characters shorter :-D

Answer (score 3):

Two ways depending on how specific you want to be:

```
# in your model
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  # first way
  named_scope :coloured, {:conditions => ["color IS NOT NULL"]}
  # second way
  named_scope :not_null, lambda{|*args| (field=args.first ? {:conditions => ["#{field} is not null",field]} : {}) } }
end

# in your controller
@coloured_widgets = Widget.coloured.all           # using first way
@coloured_widgets = Widget.not_null(:colour).all  # using second way
```

I hope it helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
Widget.find(:all, :conditions => "color IS NOT NULL")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite as elegant, but this should work:

```
Widget.find(:all, :conditions => "'color' IS NOT NULL")
```